# Spring interceptions not working

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, interceptor

I know that this have been asked a lot of times, but none of them could make my code work. I might be doing something wrong but I can't find out what.

I'm using Spring Boot with AngularJS, what I'm trying to do is to preHandle all the requests.

This is my code:

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = { "/user" })
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getLanguage() {
        return "user";
    }
}
```

Interceptor:

```
@Component
public class RequestHandler extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws ServletException {
      System.out.println("intercepted");
      return false;
  }
}
```

WebConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  HandlerInterceptor requestHandler;

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(requestHandler);
  }
}
```

And I added this to the applicationContext.xml:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="server.RequestHandler" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

I've been all the weekend trying to make this work and I couldn't, any help will be really appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to inject the RequestHandler and not the general HandlerInterceptor.  Or register your interceptor with registry.addInterceptor(new RequestHandler())?

Comment: I have tried that but it still not working.

Comment: Why do you have both xml and java config for setting up Spring MVC... That is trouble waiting to happen... Also without either `@EnableWebMvc` or `<mvc:annotation-driven />` those configs aren't going to much, the same applies if you manually configured the `HandlerAdapter` and/or `HandlerMapping`.

Comment: And how can I do that? Can you give me an example of what changes do I have to do in order to try if it works?

Answer (score 2):

You could try defining the `Bean` manually without declaring your `Interceptor` as a `@Component` like this:

*RequestHandler.java*

```
public class RequestHandler extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("intercepted");
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

*WebConfig.java*

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public RequestHandler requestHandler() {
        return new RequestHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(final InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(requestHandler());
    } 
}
```

And by the way: If the class is declared as an interceptor why no renaming it to something which contains the term *Interceptor* in it such as `RequestInterceptor`?

It should work straightforward. Please let me know if that did the trick for you!

Update: I've implemented this in a prototype. See this minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Hope it helps!
https://github.com/dbubenheim/stackoverflow-41794738.git

Comment: I tried that but says that it can creates a bean there. I don't know what else can I do because I have tried a lot of things. May I have to set something in the web.xml? Because mine is empty, I tried to set the servlet mapping there but it says that it can be declared or something like that.

Comment: I've updated my answer and added a minimal example. Perhaps you have the time to verify it works for you.

Comment: Also I have to mention that the return value of the `preHandle` method should be `true` in order to complete the request-handler-chain and reach your controller method. Please have a look at this as well @Motomine

Comment: What I wanted is not to return it, just to test if it works or not, but the page always loads.

Comment: I think you got me wrong on this. Did you have a look at or checkout my example? Your code should work the same. Interceptor is being called during each request

Comment: And what do you mean by "the page always loads"?

Comment: Because if I return false the page doesn't have to load. I tried returning ture too, but I tried redirecting and nothing happened.

Comment: this helped me while try to do https://dzone.com/articles/correlation-id-for-logging-in-microservices, i declared my intercepter as @ Component and i @ Autowired the interceptor bean and registry.addInterceptor